# How to change colors based on user selection using NotificationCenter in UIKit?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am trying to change the color of the text in a `UITableView` in UIKit. The idea is the user will go to a `UIViewController` called `AccentColorVC`, where they can choose a color. I want this to change the color of the text in the `UITableView` in the `SettingsVC`. I refactored the code a bit so that only one cell will show up.

I am trying to use the `NotificationCenter` to implement this. However, whenever the user selects a color in `AccentColorVC` and tries go back, the screen ends up freezing, and I am unable to go back to `SettingsVC`. I'm not sure why this is happening.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

AccentColorVC - Where the user selects a color:

```
class AccentColorVC: UIViewController {
    
    let tableView = UITableView()
    let identifier = "AccentColorCell"
    
    let cells: [AccentColorTVCell] = [
        AccentColorTVCell(color: .systemRed, label: "Red", isChosen: false),
        AccentColorTVCell(color: .systemGreen, label: "Green", isChosen: false),
        AccentColorTVCell(color: .systemBlue, label: "Blue", isChosen: false),
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        configureViewController()
        configureTableView()
    }
    
    private func configureViewController() {
        title = "Accent Color"
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    }
    
    private func configureTableView() {
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        
        tableView.rowHeight = 80
        
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
    }
}

extension AccentColorVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cells.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return cells[indexPath.row]
    }
    
    // MARK: - UITableViewDelegate
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        
        let selectedColor = cells[indexPath.row].color
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .colorDidChange, object: nil, userInfo: ["color": selectedColor])
    }
    
}
```

SettingsVC - Where the user sees the color being changed on the text.

```
import UIKit

class SettingsVC: UIViewController {
    
    let tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .insetGrouped)
    let toggleSwitch = UISwitch()
    var selectedColor: UIColor = .label
    let identifier = "SettingsCell"
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        configureViewController()
        configureTableView()
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didReceiveColorChangeNotification(_:)), name: .colorDidChange, object: nil)
        
    }
    
    @objc func didReceiveColorChangeNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
        guard let color = notification.userInfo?["color"] as? UIColor else { return }
        self.selectedColor = color
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    private func configureViewController() {
        title = "Settings"
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    }
    
    private func configureTableView() {
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
    }
}

extension SettingsVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath)
        
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Change Accent Color"
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = selectedColor // THIS IS WHERE I WANT THE CHANGE BEING MADE
            cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
            
        }
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            print("Change Accent Color selected")
            navigationController?.pushViewController(AccentColorVC(), animated: true)
        }
        
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
    
}
```

AccentColorTVCell: The cell being used to popular the table view in AccentColorVC

```
class AccentColorTVCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    let colorIcon = UIView()
    let colorLabel = UILabel()
    let colorSelected = UIImageView(image: UIImage(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill"))
    
    var color: UIColor
    var label: String
    var isChosen: Bool

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        self.color = .clear
        self.label = ""
        self.isChosen = false
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        configureCell()
    }
    
    init(color: UIColor, label: String, isChosen: Bool) {
        self.color = color
        self.label = label
        self.isChosen = isChosen
        super.init(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        
        configureCell()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) { fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented") }
    
    private func configureCell() {
        addSubview(colorIcon)
        addSubview(colorLabel)
        addSubview(colorSelected)
        
        colorIcon.backgroundColor = color
        colorIcon.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        
        colorLabel.text = label
        colorLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24, weight: .bold)
        
        colorSelected.tintColor = isChosen ? UIColor.systemBlue : UIColor.clear
        
        let padding: CGFloat = 20
        colorIcon.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        colorLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        colorSelected.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            colorIcon.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor),
            colorIcon.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: padding),
            colorIcon.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60),
            colorIcon.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60),
            
            colorLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor),
            colorLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: colorIcon.trailingAnchor, constant: 24),
            colorLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -padding),
            colorLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
            
            colorSelected.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor),
            colorSelected.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -padding),
            colorSelected.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24),
            colorSelected.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24)
        ])
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, the code you've posted throws some compiler errors, e.g. you didn't include a AccentColorTVCell class, as well as some conceptual errors in the use of the table view. It's hard, at least for me, to make the code runnable without changing also some of your code logic, and if I do so i can't understand your issue and answer you. Make sure to fix the sample project so that it can be built and run first.

Comment: I can, however, post the way I'd design and code what you're trying to achieve, which might be different from your design.

Comment: @oneshot The compile errors were because I did not include the `UITableViewCell` code. I have now included it. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: @oneshot I am totally fine with you showing your own implementation though.

Comment: Honestly, I just tested your project on my simulator and it works totally fine for me. I don't really agree with the hard coded cells and some other stuff using table views, as well as with the use of notification center over the delegate pattern, but it already works as you intended. The issue must be somewhere else in your code.

Comment: @oneshot Huh, that is weird. I guess I’ll try to figure out the problem. In the meantime, you said you didnt agree with using hard coded cells for my `UITableView`. I am stoll rather new to UIKit, so I’m wondering what a better way would be to go about this?

Comment: You should hard code the colors at best, and use dequeueReusableCell() ( don't forget as! AccentColorTVCell). Back to the question, I set SettingsVC as root vc of the nav and it works, maybe the issue is related to your nav logic, I can't tell.

Comment: @oneshot I figured out what the problem was. When I try adding more cells to `SettingsVC`, I get the frozen screen. If I only show the one cell thay changes color, it works as intended. Any insight as to why this is happening?

Comment: Post your full code in the question, it’s impossible to tell as of now.

Answer (score 0):

Your app may have crashed. You should use `tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath)` to get cells instead of storing all cells in array.

I added all possible colours in an enum (in case you add more colors in future, you don't need to edit any view/view controller, just add your new color in enum).

**Data Enum**

```swift
enum MyColors:CaseIterable{
    case green
    case red
    case blue
    
    var name:String{
        switch self {
        case .green:
            return "Green"
        case .red:
            return "Red"
        case .blue:
            return "Blue"
        }
    }
    
    var Color:UIColor{
        switch self {
        case .green:
            return .systemGreen
        case .red:
            return .systemRed
        case .blue:
            return .systemBlue
        }
    }
}
```

**Updated AccentColorTVCell and  AccentColorVC**

```swift
class AccentColorTVCell: UITableViewCell {
    private let colorIcon = UIView()
    private let colorLabel = UILabel()
    private let colorSelected = UIImageView(image: UIImage(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill"))
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        configureCell()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) { fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented") }
    
    private func configureCell() {
        addSubview(colorIcon)
        addSubview(colorLabel)
        addSubview(colorSelected)
        
        colorIcon.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        colorLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24, weight: .bold)
        colorSelected.isHidden = true
                
        let padding: CGFloat = 20
        colorIcon.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        colorLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        colorSelected.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            colorIcon.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor),
            colorIcon.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: padding),
            colorIcon.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60),
            colorIcon.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60),
            
            colorLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor),
            colorLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: colorIcon.trailingAnchor, constant: 24),
            colorLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -padding),
            colorLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
            
            colorSelected.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor),
            colorSelected.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -padding),
            colorSelected.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24),
            colorSelected.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24)
        ])
    }
    
    func upadateView(with detail:MyColors){
        self.colorIcon.backgroundColor = detail.Color
        self.colorLabel.text = detail.name
    }
    
    func updateToSelectionState(){
        colorSelected.isHidden = false
    }
    
    func updateToDeselectedState(){
        colorSelected.isHidden = true
    }
}
    
class AccentColorVC: UIViewController {
    let tableView = UITableView()
    let identifier = "AccentColorCell"
    
    let colors = MyColors.allCases

    var selectedColor:MyColors
    
    init(selectedColor: MyColors) {
        self.selectedColor = selectedColor
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        configureViewController()
        configureTableView()
    }
    
    private func configureViewController() {
        title = "Accent Color"
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    }
    
    private func configureTableView() {
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        
        tableView.rowHeight = 80
        
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
        tableView.register(AccentColorTVCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "uitableviewcell")

    }
}

extension AccentColorVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return colors.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier,for: indexPath) as? AccentColorTVCell else{
            return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "uitableviewcell", for: indexPath)
        }
        cell.upadateView(with: colors[indexPath.row])
        if selectedColor == colors[indexPath.row]{
            cell.updateToSelectionState()
            tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .middle)
        }
        return cell
    }
    
    // MARK: - UITableViewDelegate
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? AccentColorTVCell
        cell?.updateToSelectionState()
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .colorDidChange, object: nil, userInfo: ["color": colors[indexPath.row]])
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? AccentColorTVCell
        cell?.updateToDeselectedState()
    }
    
}

extension Notification.Name{
    static let colorDidChange = Notification.Name( "colorDidChange")
}
```

**Updated SettingsVC**

```swift
class SettingsVC: UIViewController {
    let tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .insetGrouped)
    let toggleSwitch = UISwitch()
    
    var defaultSelectedColor = MyColors.red
    lazy var selectedColor:MyColors = defaultSelectedColor
    
    let identifier = "SettingsCell"
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        configureViewController()
        configureTableView()
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didReceiveColorChangeNotification(_:)), name: .colorDidChange, object: nil)
    }
    
    @objc func didReceiveColorChangeNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
        guard let color = notification.userInfo?["color"] as? MyColors else { return }
        self.selectedColor = color
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    private func configureViewController() {
        title = "Settings"
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    }
    
    private func configureTableView() {
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
    }
}

extension SettingsVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath)
        
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Change Accent Color"
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = selectedColor.Color
            cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
            
        }
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            print("Change Accent Color selected")
            navigationController?.pushViewController(AccentColorVC(selectedColor: selectedColor), animated: true)
        }
        
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}
```

[image]